Persisting YT iframe player when changing routes in nextJS 14
I have a server component which loads info about a user video, like so
const MyPage = async() => {
  const user: SessionUser = (await requireAuth(false)) as SessionUser;
  const currentVideo = await getCurrentLeadershipMinuteVideo(user.id);

  return (
    <div>
      <Script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></Script>
      {!currentVideo ? (
        <p>There is no Video available at this time</p>
      ) : (
        <VideoPlayer currentVideo={currentVideo} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

My client component renders the iframe using the link from the server component.
const VideoPlayer = (props: LeadershipMinuteVideoProps) => {
  const { currentVideo } = props;
  const link = currentVideo.link as string;
  const title = currentVideo.title as string;

  const iframeRef = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement | null>(null);
  const playerRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);
  
  const pauseVideo = () => {
    playerRef.current.pauseVideo();
  };

  const playVideo = (): boolean => { // returns false if I remove destroy() function
    if (playerRef.current && playerRef.current.playVideo) {
      playerRef.current.playVideo();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };


  const onPlayerStateChange = (event: any) => {
    if (event.data === window.YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      //...
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
      if (iframeRef.current) {
        playerRef.current = new window.YT.Player(iframeRef.current, {
          events: {
            onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange,
          },
        });
      }
    };

    if (window.YT && window.YT.Player) {
      onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
    } else {
      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
    }

    return () => {
      if (playerRef.current) {
        playerRef.current.destroy(); // keep ?
      }
    };
  }, [playerRef]);

  return (
    <>
      <iframe
        ref={iframeRef}
        width="884"
        height="497"
        src={link + '?enablejsapi=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&autoplay=0'}
        title={title}
        style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}
        frameBorder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        referrerPolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
        allowFullScreen
      ></iframe>

      {!isPlaying && (
        <Button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            const didPlay = playVideo();
            if (didPlay) setIsPlaying(true);
          }}
        >
          Play
        </Button>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

The issue is that when I navigate away from this page (using Link from 'next/link') and come back to it, the iframe is destroyed. I understand I am destroying it in my useEffect cleanup, but do not understand why it is not re-instantiated when I navigate back to the page. Can someone explain why this happens?
When I comment out the playerRef.current.destroy() the iframe re-appears, but the fuctions associated with the YT player do not exist, i.e. "Uncaught TypeError: playerRef.current.playVideo is not a function". Any help would be appreciated
